# Where to find datasets related to US elections at the individual level?

Tags: dataset, politics

I am currently looking for datasets that I can use to predict how an individual voter will vote in a US election.

Ideally, the dataset that I am looking for includes socioeconomic features such as age, sex, income, county, and include an outcome variable for the party/candidate that this person cast their vote for.

Given that voting is highly confidential, it has been hard to really find such data - though I'm wondering if anyone on CrossValidated knows of anything out there or knows of a different dataset that I could use to predict how a particular individual will vote.

Comment: This is not the right forum for this question. Try http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37195/data

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov The Data Q&A site would be a very good fit but it is not open yet. Our only options right now seems to be (1) answer the question here (2) close/delete it entirely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[American National Election Studies](http://www.electionstudies.org/)

[Annenberg Election Surveys](http://www.annenbergpublicpolicycenter.org/tag/data-sets/)

[ICPSR Various exit polls](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/studies?q=exit+polls&permit%5B0%5D=AVAILABLE)

For ICPSR, you need a university affiliation, I think.  The general social survey also has voting questions, google it.

Comment: Thank you! Ended up going with this http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/studies/29182?permit%5B0%5D=AVAILABLE&q=exit+polls&paging.rows=25&sortBy=7

Comment: The (US) General Social Survey is available from public sources. No university affiliation needed. Hey, this is an election year (2016) with some rather interesting "correlates" , er, did  I misspell "candidates".